# Populate the whole window menu path when clicking a row in a grid in a PowerBuilder application

Tags: menu, powerbuilder, populate

I am using PB 10.5.2 and I have made an application in which, when I open a form and retrieve some data in a DataWindow grid, by double-clicking any row, I want to populate the whole window menu path of a specific menu item...thus for example I want by clicking that row in the grid to open a menu item with the whole menu path extended.
Is there any way to do that with code, PowerScript or something similar?

e.g

FILE

|

|
->SAVE

```
   |

   |

    -> SAVE AS

    -> SAVE ALL
```

and I want to open the whole path of "save as" ==> (FILE-> SAVE -> SAVE AS) and make it open and visible.

Thanks very much in advance !

Answer (score 1):

A user would not expect a menu to open up like that. If double-clicking invokes a save as operation, just open the save as dialog.

Comment: Let'say I have a Single Line Edit box in a form and a button, and I write a keyword in the Single Line edit box and press the button. I want to search the whole menu of the form to find where this word exists...And let's say for example that this word exists once...I want the menu to open and extend the whole dropdown and cascaded menu till the menu item. That is what Iam trying to find out..!!! Is there any way either by PFC or API or something else to implememt it? Thanks a lot for your reply !!!!